# Move shared_ptr with unrelated pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11

I have a piece of code which passes around buffers of data. I want to manage the lifetime of these buffers and so that the memory will not be freed before I am done using it. I realize that `std::shared_ptr` is suitable for this task. One thing I want to do is to pass a portion of a buffer to a function while still maintaining the ownership information of the entire buffer (e.g. cut off a header and pass the body to another function).

I noticed that `std::shared_ptr` has the following constructor:

```
template< class Y >
shared_ptr( const shared_ptr<Y>& r, T *ptr );
```

This constructor allows me to create a new `shared_ptr` that shares ownership with `r` but stores the pointer `ptr`. This is great, but this will cause an increase in the reference count. In some cases, I may wish to pass a portion of a buffer without retaining a `shared_ptr` to it. In such a case, I wouldn't need an increase in the reference count. It seems like I would need the following constructor:

```
template< class Y >
shared_ptr( shared_ptr<Y>&& r, T *ptr );
```

Note that `r` is an rvalue reference. It doesn't appear that such a constructor exists for `std::shared_ptr`. Is there a reason for this? Is there a way to do what I want without increasing the reference count?

Comment: I'd say the ctor doesn't exist because it seems like a rather infrequent case. I'd also say you shouldn't worry about it until you discover it to be a performance bottleneck (which I don't think you ever will).

Answer (score 1):

It may not exist, however there is little reason that should worry you.

Certainly the reference count is incremented when copying a shared pointer, but on the other hand it is decremented when destroying one; and thus:

```
std::shared_ptr<T> some_pointer = /**/;

std::shared_ptr<R> another_pointer(some_pointer, some_pointer->field());

some_pointer.reset();
```

Will be semantically identical to a move, and just generate a couple more instructions (if not optimized out).

Comment: +1. ... couple more *atomic* instructions, but still not worh thinking about until profiling proves otherwise, I'd say.

Comment: I disagree, suppose I am using this in the network stack of a kernel. Every different protocol that wants to read a header and pass on the rest to another function (which itself might do the same) must add two additional atomic operations (~100 cycles each). The cost can certainly add up on such a critical path.

Comment: @dschatz: I did not say that it would be unnoticeable, just that it would be fast. If it's not in the Standard, it's not. You can prepare a paper for inclusion in the next Standard but in the mean time you'll have to work around it; I simply meant to propose a simple way of achieving the same functionality. If you really are writing performance critical code, then you will have to profile and check whether it's fast enough (ie, is it noticeable after processing the header ?). And if it is not, then implement a faster work-around.